# C++17: using std::optional to evaluate if enum contains value

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, constexpr, stdoptional

I'd like to check at compile-time if various enums contain a given value, so I've written the following:

```
#include <optional>

enum class test_enum : int {
    VALUE_0 = 0,
    VALUE_1 = 1
};

// Template function to perform check
template<typename T>
constexpr std::optional<T> from_int(int value)
{
    static_assert(false, __FUNCTION__ " not implemented for this type; see build output");
    return std::optional<T>();
}

// Specialization for test_enum
template<>
constexpr std::optional<test_enum> from_int(int value)
{
    switch (value) {
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_0) :
            return test_enum::VALUE_0;
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_1):
            return test_enum::VALUE_1;
        default:
            return std::optional<test_enum>();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static_assert(from_int<test_enum>(1));

    return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.8.6), the code compiles successfully with no errors in the output. However, the error window shows

```
E0028: expression must have a constant value" at line 30. (the first line of main)
```

and

```
"std::_Optional_construct_base<test_enum>::_Optional_construct_base(std::in_place_t, _Types &&..._Args) [with _Types=<test_enum>]" (declared implicitly) is not defined)".
```

Any hints as to why this is? I can ignore E0028, but I'd prefer not to if possible.

**EDIT:** Removing the static_assert from from_int does not change the error.

Comment: Just so you know, `static_assert(false)` makes the primary template ill-formed with no diagnostic required. One compiler may accept it silently, another may fire the static assertion immediately.

Comment: @StoryTeller Does statically asserting with std::false_type fix that? I tried std::false_type and Igor R's suggestion for false_t<test_enum> and Visual Studio shows no change.

Comment: Oh it's not an attempt to answer your question. Just wanted to warn against something that may rear its head later. The false constant expression must be dependant. Since `std::false_type` by itself is also not dependant it shares the same problem.

Comment: Cool, I appreciate it.

Comment: BTW, what is "line 30"?

Comment: Ah, my bad. It's `static_assert(from_int<test_enum>(1));` in main().

Comment: Please note that this is fixed in VS v15.9.0-pre.1.0 (cl v19.15.26726).

Comment: @Swordfish Thanks for the heads up! How do you know that?

Comment: I compiled your code with it.

Comment: Legit, thanks for testing it out! If you post that as a separate answer, I'd be happy to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question compiles without warnings or errors using `cl` v19.15.26726 (Visual Studio version 15.9.0-pre.1.0)

Comment: Sweet, thank you. I'll see if I can suppress the error for now and make a note to remove the workaround after updating.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the Standard defines such a code as ill-formed, no diagnostics required. Take a look at the following statements:

> [The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation.
> [ Note: Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every
> template to be checked in this way. — end note ] The program is
> ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> <...>
>
> (8.4) a hypothetical
> instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would
> be ill-formed due to a construct that does not depend on a template
> parameter...]    [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8)

To make it well-formed, do not use `static_assert(false)`. Instead, use the following trick (compiles with GCC 7 and CLang 7):

```
#include <optional>

enum class test_enum : int {
    VALUE_0 = 0,
    VALUE_1 = 1
};

template<typename T> 
constexpr bool false_t = false;

// Template function to perform check
template<typename T>
constexpr std::optional<T> from_int(int value)
{
    static_assert(false_t<T>, "Not implemented for this type; see build output");
    return std::optional<T>();
}

// Specialization for test_enum
template<>
constexpr std::optional<test_enum> from_int<test_enum>(int value)
{
    switch (value) {
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_0) :
            return test_enum::VALUE_0;
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_1):
            return test_enum::VALUE_1;
        default:
            return std::optional<test_enum>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(from_int<test_enum>(1));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that (and static_asserting with std::false_type) result in the same error in Visual Studio. Did the original code compile under GCC 7?

EDIT: I see from StoryTeller's comment that Visual Studio should technically not accept the original template.

Comment: @tstevens MSVC is another story... Typically, it has a poor compliance with the standard.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it. MSDN claims that Visual Studio 2017 is fully compliant with std::optional, so I guess this may be a bug.

Comment: @tstevens - To be exact, MSVC doesn't have to reject it. The standard doesn't require a diagnostic, so it's not exactly non-conformant on MSVC's behalf. One can argue it's a poor QoI, however.

Comment: @StoryTeller I wasn't very clear -- I meant the fact that Visual Studio rejects the call to from_int() in main (even after removing from_int()'s static assert) seems like a bug.

Comment: @tstevens - Oh, I was referring to your first comment. Apologies for any and all confusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller No worries, thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 3):

It is far better to use tag dispatching than template specialziation in 99/100 cases.

```
#include <optional>

enum class test_enum : int {
    VALUE_0 = 0,
    VALUE_1 = 1
};

template<class T> struct tag_t {};

namespace from_int_details {
  template<class T>
  std::optional<T> from_int_impl( tag_t<T>, int value ) = delete;
}
template<class T>
std::optional<T> from_int( int value ) {
  using namespace from_int_details;
  return from_int_impl( tag_t<T>{}, value );
}

// Overload for test_enum, same namespace as test_enum *or* in from_int_details:
constexpr std::optional<test_enum> from_int_impl(tag_t<test_enum>, int value)
{
    switch (value) {
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_0) :
            return test_enum::VALUE_0;
        case static_cast<int>(test_enum::VALUE_1):
            return test_enum::VALUE_1;
        default:
            return std::optional<test_enum>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(from_int<test_enum>(1));
}
```

here people extend `from_int` by writing a `constexpr optional<the_enum_type> from_int_impl( tag_t<the_enum_type>, int )` either in the namespace of `the_enum_type` (so it can be found via ADL), or for enums where this isn't possible (like enums in `std`), in the `from_int_details` namespace.  Or the namespace of `tag_t`.

Here is this code compiling in [MSVC 2017](https://godbolt.org/z/w6jnI-), compiler version 19.10.

Comment: Why is tag dispatching better? To me, specializing from_int() is more readable because it doesn't require writing from_int_impl(), which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. I'm using this in a library where I don't want the library user to have to consider the differences between from_int() and from_int_impl() -- I'd rather them only see from_int().

Comment: Because it allows customization to occur in the namespace of the enum.  Because the `=delete` is legal, while `static_assert(false` is not.  Because workarounds of `static_assert(false` are only arguably legal (depending on interpretation of standard requirements that require templates functions to have a valid body for some type). Because `_impl` is optional; remove it and the code still works.  Because specialization of template functions is athema that introducrs a highly counterintuitive counterpoint to already complex C++ overload rules.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Appreciate the followup. I should have specified in my original question that the test_enum is in namespace A::B, where from_int is in namespace A. I've been able to specialize the template just fine in different namespaces. From the end user's perspective, using tag_t just changes the function call from from_int<test_enum>() to from_int(tag_t<test_enum>). How is that thematically different from specializing the template function directly?

Comment: Also, I'm inclined to keep the static assert because it allows me to provide a simple, customized error message to the user (you've seen the usual template compiler errors -- they're not exactly easy to read if your user isn't super familiar with C++).

Comment: @tstevens The user never has to use `tag_t` unless adding a new overload; user-code just does `some_ns::from_int<test_enum>`..  Template specialization only works in the namespace where the template was originally declared.  I understand why you want to use `static_assert( false, ` or a hack to do so; I am saying that doing so while justifying your program is well formed requires a lot of faith in a specific reading of the standard that your compiler may disagree with (if not today, eventually).  Ie, your code could break in arbitrary ways in future compiler updates.

Comment: If your template is in `namespace A`, specializations must be in `namespace A`.  If you aren't in `namespace A` you might think you are specializing while you are actually overloading, or something else strange.  In any case, it is your code base, good luck.

Comment: Ah you're right, I definitely had to declare the specializations in namespace A. I'll keep looking template specialization vs overloading -- if I can initially define from_int() in namespace A and overload in namespace B, I'll definitely switch (and I'd forgotten about the automatic inference of tag_t based on from_int<T>). Thanks again for your comments.